# Fb.ui feed method on same window instead of new window

Tags: facebook, fbjs, facebook-javascript-sdk

The `Fb.ui` `feed` method open a new small window for posting a new feed. I want it to open postiing request in the same window and after posting redirect to same(prev) window.

Any one??

**Edited:** 
FB.init({appId: "1234567890", status: true, cookie: true});

```
  function postToFeed() {

    // calling the API ...
    var obj = {
      method: 'feed',
      display: 'touch',
      link: 'https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/dialogs/',
      picture: 'http://fbrell.com/f8.jpg',
      name: 'Facebook Dialogs',
      caption: 'Reference Documentation',
      description: 'Using Dialogs to interact with users.'
    };

    function callback(response) {
      document.getElementById('msg').innerHTML = "Post ID: " + response['post_id'];
    }

    FB.ui(obj, callback);
  }
```

@Nitzan Tomer

Yes this opens the dialogue box, but this thing doesn't work in iPhones/iPads. If works then i dont want to open a new window/tab for it, but want the whole process(auth and posting) in the same window where the user is/were.

Comment: FB.ui should open a dialog on the same window, not as a popup and after posting it should just close. If this is not the behavior you're getting then something is wrong, can you please post the code you are using? (including the sdk load/init)

Answer (score 1):

You can use redirect url method given on [Facebook Developer website](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/dialogs/feed/).

```
https://www.facebook.com/dialog/feed?
  app_id=123050457758183&
  link=https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/dialogs/&
  picture=http://fbrell.com/f8.jpg&
  name=Facebook%20Dialogs&
  caption=Reference%20Documentation&
  description=Using%20Dialogs%20to%20interact%20with%20users.&
  redirect_uri=http://www.example.com/response
```